# Parsing XML files with repeated tag names that have differing data using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, beautifulsoup

```
<ValueList><Count>62</Count><MaxCount>62</MaxCount>
<Value ref="123456"> <DisplayName origin="UID"><100056></DisplayName><DisplayName origin="Default"><![CDATA[Xee]]></DisplayName><UniqueAlias><![CDATA[STATUS=Active]]></UniqueAlias><UniqueAlias><![CDATA[ORG=abcd]]></UniqueAlias><Hierarchy><![CDATA[xee]]></Hierarchy><AdditionalField label="Organisation"><![CDATA[MC/x]]></AdditionalField><AdditionalField label="Country"><![CDATA[Singapore]]></AdditionalField><AdditionalField label="ProjectStatus"><![CDATA[Active]]></AdditionalField></Value>
<Value ref="1234567"> <DisplayName origin="UID"><100046></DisplayName><DisplayName origin="Default"><![CDATA[Xabc]]></DisplayName><UniqueAlias><![CDATA[STATUS=Active]]></UniqueAlias><UniqueAlias><![CDATA[ORG=efgh]]></UniqueAlias><Hierarchy><![CDATA[Gee]]></Hierarchy><AdditionalField label="Organisation"><![CDATA[MC/h]]></AdditionalField><AdditionalField label="Country"><![CDATA[Malaysia]]></AdditionalField><AdditionalField label="ProjectStatus"><![CDATA[Active]]></AdditionalField></Value>
<Value ref="8984379"> <DisplayName origin="UID"><100066></DisplayName><DisplayName origin="Default"><![CDATA[WRFMDS]]></DisplayName><UniqueAlias><![CDATA[STATUS=Active]]></UniqueAlias><UniqueAlias><![CDATA[ORG=test1]]></UniqueAlias><Hierarchy><![CDATA[LEE]]></Hierarchy><AdditionalField label="Organisation"><![CDATA[MC/K]]></AdditionalField><AdditionalField label="Country"><![CDATA[USA]]></AdditionalField><AdditionalField label="ProjectStatus"><![CDATA[Active]]></AdditionalField></Value>
<Value ref="1234567"> <DisplayName origin="UID"><100446></DisplayName><DisplayName origin="Default"><![CDATA[LKGJSML]]></DisplayName><UniqueAlias><![CDATA[STATUS=Active]]></UniqueAlias><UniqueAlias><![CDATA[ORG=KLPS]]></UniqueAlias><Hierarchy><![CDATA[abeed]]></Hierarchy><AdditionalField label="Organisation"><![CDATA[MC/L]]></AdditionalField><AdditionalField label="Country"><![CDATA[uk]]></AdditionalField><AdditionalField label="ProjectStatus"><![CDATA[Active]]></AdditionalField></Value>
</valueList>
```

from the above xml type i want to extract the following values and create a data frame .

1. ref value "123456" from the value tag
2. value "STATUS=Active" from the "UniqueAlias" tag.
3. value "ORG=test1" from the "UniqueAlias" tag.
4. Value "Xee" from the "Hierarchy" tag ,
5. value "Singapore" from the "AdditionalField label="Country" tag
6. value "MC/x" from "AdditionalField label="Organisation" tag

create a data frame by looping through the same tags in xml file.

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. Thanks

Comment: Make sure the XML you post is **VALID** . The current one is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to extract each element separately. The following example should get you started:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

xml = """<ValueList>
<Count>62</Count><MaxCount>62</MaxCount>
<Value ref="123456"> <DisplayName origin="UID"><100056></DisplayName><DisplayName origin="Default"><![CDATA[Xee]]></DisplayName><UniqueAlias><![CDATA[STATUS=Active]]></UniqueAlias><UniqueAlias><![CDATA[ORG=abcd]]></UniqueAlias><Hierarchy><![CDATA[xee]]></Hierarchy><AdditionalField label="Organisation"><![CDATA[MC/x]]></AdditionalField><AdditionalField label="Country"><![CDATA[Singapore]]></AdditionalField><AdditionalField label="ProjectStatus"><![CDATA[Active]]></AdditionalField></Value>
<Value ref="1234567"> <DisplayName origin="UID"><100046></DisplayName><DisplayName origin="Default"><![CDATA[Xabc]]></DisplayName><UniqueAlias><![CDATA[STATUS=Active]]></UniqueAlias><UniqueAlias><![CDATA[ORG=efgh]]></UniqueAlias><Hierarchy><![CDATA[Gee]]></Hierarchy><AdditionalField label="Organisation"><![CDATA[MC/h]]></AdditionalField><AdditionalField label="Country"><![CDATA[Malaysia]]></AdditionalField><AdditionalField label="ProjectStatus"><![CDATA[Active]]></AdditionalField></Value>
<Value ref="8984379"> <DisplayName origin="UID"><100066></DisplayName><DisplayName origin="Default"><![CDATA[WRFMDS]]></DisplayName><UniqueAlias><![CDATA[STATUS=Active]]></UniqueAlias><UniqueAlias><![CDATA[ORG=test1]]></UniqueAlias><Hierarchy><![CDATA[LEE]]></Hierarchy><AdditionalField label="Organisation"><![CDATA[MC/K]]></AdditionalField><AdditionalField label="Country"><![CDATA[USA]]></AdditionalField><AdditionalField label="ProjectStatus"><![CDATA[Active]]></AdditionalField></Value>
<Value ref="1234567"> <DisplayName origin="UID"><100446></DisplayName><DisplayName origin="Default"><![CDATA[LKGJSML]]></DisplayName><UniqueAlias><![CDATA[STATUS=Active]]></UniqueAlias><UniqueAlias><![CDATA[ORG=KLPS]]></UniqueAlias><Hierarchy><![CDATA[abeed]]></Hierarchy><AdditionalField label="Organisation"><![CDATA[MC/L]]></AdditionalField><AdditionalField label="Country"><![CDATA[uk]]></AdditionalField><AdditionalField label="ProjectStatus"><![CDATA[Active]]></AdditionalField></Value>
</valueList>"""

data = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "html.parser")

for value in soup.valuelist.find_all('value'):
    additional_fields = [field.text for field in value.find_all('additionalfield')]

    data.append([
        value['ref'],
        value.uniquealias.text,
        value.hierarchy.text,
        additional_fields[1],
        additional_fields[0],
    ])

    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Value', 'UniqueAlias', 'Hierarchy', 'AddField1', 'AddField2'])

print(df)
```

Giving you a single row dataframe:

```
     Value    UniqueAlias Hierarchy  AddField1 AddField2
0   123456  STATUS=Active       xee  Singapore      MC/x
1  1234567  STATUS=Active       Gee   Malaysia      MC/h
2  8984379  STATUS=Active       LEE        USA      MC/K
3  1234567  STATUS=Active     abeed         uk      MC/L
```

Comment: Thanks Martin , this did really help .  do you have any idea how to loop this through an entire xml file and fetch all the row?

Comment: You would need to parse the entire XML file as soup. You can then use `find_all()` on the containing list. You would need to [edit] your question to add some more details

Comment: '<UniqueAlias><![CDATA[STATUS=Active]]></UniqueAlias><UniqueAlias><![CDATA[ORG=abcd]]></UniqueAlias> ` , if both the tags are in same name  how would we extract the data separately ?

Comment: I would need to see more of the XML file, i.e. what comes before the row you have shown, can you add it to your question or provide a URL to the file?

Comment: I have updated sample format in the question